# How to create a timeline without integer number for events?

Tags: floats, chronosys

In my paper, I wish to create a timeline figure, to show what happens between "period t" and "period t+1", instead of "real time numbers" like `1978`. It is not allowed in the package `chronosys`.

Comment: Please specify what you want to do. You don't want to print the actual dates as numbers? Do you want a numberline? Maybe you can include your code.

Comment: I don't want to print dates as numbers. I want to show readers what events happened between $t$ and $t+1$ with a line.

Comment: So a line with start and end dates and text underneath?

Comment: Yes, a line with an arrow from left to right. A wide sub-interval of the line is from $t$ to $t+1$. And I need to put several events into that sub-interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I've gotten around to do a quick and dirty version of what you might have in mind. It doesn't use the `chronosys` package, because I don't know it. Instead I used `tikz`. I hope it still helps.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\def \Tstart {1800}
\def \Tend {1900}
\pgfmathsetmacro\Tduration {(\Tend - \Tstart)}
\def \ImageWidth {13}
\pgfmathsetmacro\scaling {(\ImageWidth/\Tduration)}

\newcommand\timelineDateBelow[2]{% (date, text)
  \pgfmathsetmacro \xdate {(#1 - \Tstart)*\scaling}
  \draw (\xdate,0.1) -- (\xdate,-0.1) node[below, align=center, text width = 2cm]{#2};
}
\newcommand\timelineDateAbove[2]{% (date, text)
  \pgfmathsetmacro \xdate {(#1 - \Tstart)*\scaling}
  \draw (\xdate,0.1) node[above, align=center, text width = 2cm]{#2} -- (\xdate,-0.1);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[ultra thick, ->] (0,0) -- (\ImageWidth,0);
% start and finish dates and ticks
%  \draw[ultra thick] (0,0.1) node[above]{\Tstart} -- (0,-0.1);
%  \draw (\ImageWidth,0.1) node[above]{\Tend};

  \timelineDateBelow{1810}{date a here}
  \timelineDateBelow{1840}{manual\\linebreak}
  \timelineDateAbove{1860}{date b above}
  \timelineDateBelow{1870}{date c here}
  \timelineDateAbove{1880}{date d above to avoid overlap}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Let me tell you the weaknesses. The text can overlap, if you set the dates too close together. You can avoid it by lowering the `text width` for the nodes, which is set manually to `text width=2cm` or by manually breaking the line.

You also have to manually adjust the horizontal scaling. It is set to an arbitrary number in `\ImageWidth`. I'm sure there is a way to get it to automatically fill the linewidth, but that messed up my calculations. Maybe someone knows how to do calculations with `\linewidth` in the comment.

Hope this is a start to get you going. Let me know, if that's what you were looking for or if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks, Ben! It looks good.
Two minor modifications I wish:
1. "1800" and "1900" disappear;
2. no node at the left end.
Are they feasible?

Comment: @DavidXiaoyuXu If you want, you can upvote or mark the answer as correct, so that future users will know it worked for you.

Comment: I added some words in my previous comment. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidXiaoyuXu That's really easy. I'll make some changes to the answer.

Comment: btw, is it possible to get some text above the line, and keep the rest below it?

Comment: @DavidXiaoyuXu You mean some of the date text above and some below? That's possible. Give me a minute.

Comment: Believe me, you don't *want* to become familiar with `chronosys`.