# How can I get a timeline as shown?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to recreate the following timeline for a concurrency class, but am confused how I can actually do this with Latex.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far?

Comment: I've tried implementing what is described here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272541/how-to-create-a-timeline-without-integer-number-for-events, but I was not able to remove the tick marks and arrow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to obtain something of that sort is to use `pgffgantt`. I had to "hack" it a tiny bit, though. To add a timeline item, you only need to say

```
\ganttbar{<label>}{<start>}{<end>} \\
```

For your convenience I stored the keys in a style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\newcounter{bars}
\newcounter{cheat}
\ganttset{Monya/.style={bar label font=\color{blue!60!black}\sffamily,
    canvas/.style={shape=rectangle,draw=none,alias=frame,
    append after command={
    foreach \X in {1,...,\number\value{bars}} {
    ([yshift=5pt]X\X.south-|frame.west) node{$\setcounter{cheat}{\X}\Alph{cheat}$}}}
    },inline,bar top shift=0.55,bar height=0.85,
    bar/.style={draw=none,/utils/exec=\stepcounter{bars},
    alias=X\number\value{bars},path picture={
    \draw[|-|,thick] ([yshift=3.5pt]path picture bounding box.south west) 
    -- ([yshift=3.5pt]path picture bounding box.south east);}}}}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{bars}{0}
\begin{ganttchart}[Monya]{-2}{14}
 \ganttbar{delete(1)}{0}{4} \\
 \ganttbar{getOrElseUpdate(1,0):3}{1}{3} \\
 \ganttbar{update(1,2)}{2}{8} \\
 \ganttbar{getOrElseUpdate(1,0)}{3.5}{7} \\
 \ganttbar{getOrElse(1,-1):2}{4.5}{6} \\
 \ganttbar{getOrElse(1,-1):0}{10}{12} \\
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]